# Deadlock error occuring when adding and updating record same time

Tags: php, mysql, deadlock

We are currently developing a project that have many transactions. Users add order in the queue table and another scripts process the transaction. when add transaction and queue engines work same time, occur deadlock error.

**queue table**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_queue` (
    `OrderId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `State` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '1=adding, 11=proccessing, 2=complete',
    `EngineId` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `AddTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`OrderId`),
    INDEX `State` (`State`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**adding transactions**

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->exec("INSERT INTO order_queue (OrderId, State, EngineId) VALUES ({$OrderId}, 1, 0)");
$db->commit();
```

**and finally we have three queue engine that get transaction and sending another systems**

```
$db->query("UPDATE order_queue SET State=11,EngineId={$EngineId} WHERE State=1 LIMIT 1");

$qOrder = $db->query("SELECT * FROM order_queue 
            WHERE State=11 AND EngineId={$EngineId}")->fetch();

echo $qOrder->OrderId;
//send the order to other systems
$db->exec("UPDATE order_queue SET State=2 WHERE OrderId={$qOrder->OrderId}");
```

if this script working same time, occur most beloved error

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

I tried a few methods firstly checking `AddTime`, secondly changed `State` after `$db->commit();` line etc. but the problem not solved.

If you were me, what would you do? Which method is the best?

Comment: Does "three queue engine" are run separately or in a single script?

Comment: run separately. actually these are same file, i run different time

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "lock in share mode" as below

```
$db->query("UPDATE order_queue SET State=11,EngineId={$EngineId} WHERE State=1 LIMIT 1");

$qOrder = $db->query("SELECT * FROM order_queue 
            WHERE State=11 AND EngineId={$EngineId} lock in share mode")->fetch();

echo $qOrder->OrderId;
//send the order to other systems
$db->exec("UPDATE order_queue SET State=2 WHERE OrderId={$qOrder->OrderId}");
```